# Identity Column Format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm converting some data to SQL, and one column is a ID column in the format of last 2 digits of this year, and increment +1 of the last entered row in database.

So this year first entry would be 15-001, the next entry would be 15-002 etc. I cant seem to find an example anywhere online on how to do this? i'm not sure if I could do this in a Computed Column? Using Sql Server 2012.

Thank you!

Comment: What DBMS? And, as always, what have you tried?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You described an ID column but haven't specified your desired output, etc.

Comment: Every new entry increases that number by 1. So the first entry today would be 15-001, the 5th entry would be 16-005. Next year the first entry would be 16-001. So somehow I need to take the last 2 digits of the year, and look to see what the previous entry was, and add one too that for that column.

Comment: Since you are using SQL 2012, I would suggest looking at the [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) object.  On a side note, combining two pieces of data (YY + incrementing number) into one column is a questionable design choice.  I would create a separate column for each.

Comment: I've seen it quite a bit in a lot of databases I've been messing around in lately, so for whatever reason some people believe in doing it. I'm not sure how its done though, not sure if its in a stored proc because its not in the design on the column..

Comment: Seems like a bad design to me. Identity columns can only be of integer types, and what you have is a varchar. I would keep a regular identity column and keep this data in a persisted computed column.

Comment: I agree with everyone that this is a terrible design choice.  Having "seen it before" does not make it right.  It just means someone else made a bad choice in the past.  And, I also agree with @DMason - if you want to know the year and the sequence in that year, you should have a Year and Sequence column.  These two columns could be a composite key, or, you could have a separate primary key column that doesn't include business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I highly do not recommend using an ID in the format that you are stating. You will come across many other issues. You can use this code in a stored procedure or function to get next ID value.

```
DECLARE 
  @oldID varchar(8),
  @newID varchar(8),
  @temp varchar(8),
  @number decimal,
  @day int;
begin
  SET @oldID = '15-555'; --select statement for last id
  SET @day = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
  IF ( LEN(@oldID) = 6)
    SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@oldID, 4, 6);
  ELSE
    SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@oldID, 3, 5);
  SET @number = CAST(@temp AS Decimal(10, 0));
  SET @number += 1;
  SET @temp = CAST(@number AS varchar(8));
  WHILE LEN(@temp) < 3
  begin
    SET @temp = '0' + @temp;
    end
  SET @newID = SUBSTRING(CAST(@day AS varchar(8)), 3, 4) + '-' + @temp;

  print @newID --ID that you are looking for.
end
```

Stops working correctly after 15-999 and does not reset to 16-001 if that is what your were asking. Code can be changed to account for these things.